# GridLayout weird behaviour

Tags: android, grid-layout

I'm following this tutorial on GridLayout http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/669. I've implemented the code as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:rowCount="4">

    <TextView
            android:text="1,1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
            android:text="1,2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
            android:text="1,3"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
            android:text="1,4"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
            android:text="2,1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
            android:text="2,2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
            android:text="2,3"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
            android:text="2,4"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
            android:text="3,1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
            android:text="3,2"/>

    <TextView
            android:text="3,3 longer"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
            android:text="3,4"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
            android:text="4,1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
            android:text="4,2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
            android:text="4,3"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
            android:text="4,4"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</GridLayout>
```

Which produces this grid:
[image]

If I understand how `fill_horizontal` works, it isn't making column 3 *as big as needed to fit the text*, its making column 3 *as big as possible* (because gridlayout layout_width is match_parent).

When I add some longer text to another column (say 2,2) everything changes.

```
<TextView
        android:text="1,1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<TextView
        android:text="1,2"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<TextView
        android:text="1,3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<TextView
        android:text="1,4"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<TextView
        android:text="2,1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<TextView
        android:text="2,2 longer, also"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<TextView
        android:text="2,3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<TextView
        android:text="2,4"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<TextView
        android:text="3,1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<TextView
        android:text="3,2"/>

<TextView
        android:text="3,3 longer"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<TextView
        android:text="3,4"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<TextView
        android:text="4,1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<TextView
        android:text="4,2"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<TextView
        android:text="4,3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<TextView
        android:text="4,4"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

produces:
[image]

So whats happening to change things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this 'change' does not happen when you remove the

layout_gravity="center" from the

```
      <TextView
        android:text="2,2 longer, also"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Apparently, this layout_gravity attribute causes the misbehavior. I think , this layout_gravity attribute tries to position the textView at the center of its parent (GridLayout) and interferes with the column 3 being resized to fill horizontal.